Digicert cert downloaded from Venafi
Currently, I have certificate installed from internal authority but now org is asking to download DigiCert from Venafi and install in website.
how to do that?
I downloaded PEM certificate format from Venafi but not able to install that on Apache server.
Please help.
I tried decrypting the key and convert .pem to .crt but it doesn't work.

Try to use openSSL commands to get the cert file and key file from .pfx file below are the commands openssl pkcs12 -in [yourfile.pfx] -nocerts -nodes -out [keyfile.pem]
Extract the certificate: openssl pkcs12 -in [yourfile.pfx] -clcerts -nokeys -out [certfile.pem]
then try to install on the server and give chmod 775 permissions to the file and backup the previous .cert and .key files and restart the server
